# Book about a girl who dies in an accident and is brought back to life by her parents in a robotic body

Tags: story-identification, novel, robots

It's about a girl who is in an accident and her parents bring her back to live in a robotic body that they uploaded her brain to. Nobody at school will talk to her anymore because they're creeped out.

She keeps trying to run out the batteries on her body because she doesn't need to sleep anymore.

I read this in the 2000s, maybe 2005-2007?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ***[Skinned](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2791536-skinned)*** (2008) by Robin Wasserman, the first book in the *[Cold Awakening](https://www.goodreads.com/series/50685-cold-awakening)* trilogy.

[image: Front cover of "Skinned" (2008) by Robin Wasserman.]

According to a [review](https://www.bookrags.com/studyguide-skinned/#gsc.tab=0), the novel is set in the future and follows a 17-year-old named Lia who is severely injured in a car crash. She's subsequently taken to a biotech company owned by her father, where her mind is downloaded into a mechanical body that looks human. The book starts out with her waking up in that body.

> "Skinned" is a science fiction novel by acclaimed Young Adult writer Robin Wasserman. **The novel is set in the future and follows 17-year-old Lia Kahn as she attempts to adjust to her new life after her brain is downloaded into an artificial body following a car crash.** Published in 2008, Skinned is the first novel in the "Skinned" trilogy, continued in "Crashed" (2009), and concluded in "Wired" (2010).
>
> When Lia Kahn is severely injured in a freak car accident, she is taken to BioTech - one of her father's companies - where her brain is downloaded into an artificial, mechanical body which looks and feels like a normal human body. Lia is told that she will no longer need to eat or breathe, she will not feel pain or become ill, and she will never die. During weeks of intense rehab and therapy Lia learns how to control her new body, but finds that she is unable to "feel" things the way that she used to. She is told that there will be a period of adjustment and that eventually some emotions and sensations should return.

After returning home, she finds herself shunned by her younger sister, Zo, and her friend group at school, who no longer perceive her as the same person she was before. Her new body freezes up at one point, as a result of her failing to take proper care of it.

> After her rehab is complete, Lia's parents bring her home and she immediately tries to resume the life she had led prior to the accident. **Lia had been the most popular girl in school and the leader of a tight-knit circle of friends, but she finds that things are now very different. Her sister Zo, who had never been part of her group before, has taken over her position as the leader of her friends, and her best friends treat her as though they don't know her. Even her boyfriend Walker avoids her whenever possible. She tries to explain that even though she has a new body she is the same Lia that she always was, but none of her friends are able to accept this.** After an incident at a party in which her friends believe a lie about her, Lia finds herself shunned by almost everyone she knows, including her best friends and Walker.
>
> **One day a month later, Lia's artificial body freezes in mid-step while she is walking to class as a result of her not taking proper care of herself.**

According to an excerpt of the story I found in the [Google Books preview](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Skinned/y3mEDkMA95IC?hl=en&gbpv=0), Lia didn't like shutting her new body down at night, as it made her feel like she was losing herself again, so she instead chose to run through the woods for hours, ignoring her body's warnings that she was wearing it out.

> When you sleep, your body marks the time. Yesterday lies in the dark; tomorrow wakes. Eyes open, you know. The body ages, the hourglass empties, death approaches. It wasn't like that for me, not anymore. **I couldn't shut down without feeling like I was losing myself all over again, night after night. So instead I ran.**
> I ran through the woods in the dark, full out, without fear that I would stumble over the uneven ground or the broken branches blown across the path, running faster, maybe hoping I would fall, just to see if I would hurt, and if it did, maybe that would be alright, because feeling something was better than nothing. But I never fell. And **I never stopped when I was tired. The body told me it was wearing down, but I didn't ache, I didn't cramp, I didn't wheeze. The body's monitoring system flashed red warnings across my eyes; I ignored them.** The coach, before she'd thrown me off the team, had always said that running was 90 percent mental. That was for humans, I decided. (*Orgs.* The word popped into my head, but I ignored it, because that was Jude's word, Jude and his freaks, not mine.) For me, it was all mental; the body, and whatever it wanted, was irrelevant. So I ran for hours, for miles, until I got bored, and then I ran farther until I eventually retreated to the house to wait out the dawn.
>
> <sub>*Skinned* (2008) by Robin Wasserman</sub>

Comment: This is absolutely it. Thanks!